# Find the length of the vector f(x) = x in L[0, 1]

Tags: vector-spaces, metric-spaces, vectors

Find the length of the vector $f(x) = x$ in $L_2[0, 1]$

Is the solution $L=\int\sqrt{(1+(f'(x))^2dx)}$ hence $L=\sqrt{2}$ ?

Or am I completly wrong?

Comment: It depends on the norm. Usually $\ell^2([0,1])$ has the norm $||f||=(\int_0^1 \,f^2)^{1/2}$. If so then $L=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation $L = \int_I \sqrt{1+{f'}^2}$ is the *euclidean length* of the *parametrised curve* $(x,f(x))_{x\in I}$. Here, it seems that the question is not about the length of the curve as a geometric object in the plane, but would rather be the *norm of the vector* $\mathrm{id}$ in the abstract normed linear space $\left(L^2([0,1]), \|.\|_2\right)$ where
$$
\|f\|_2 = \sqrt{\int_0^1 |f|^2}
$$
Hence, in this case
$$
\|\mathrm{id}\|_2 = \sqrt{\int_0^1 x^2 \mathrm{d}x} 
$$
This will lead to another value than $\sqrt{2}$.